# Is there any canonical chat messenger working both in android and ubuntu?

Tags: android

My friend is in china and she is using android phone. Now I use ubuntu.And in there facebook is blocked.And, kik,wechat doesn't work in pc laptop. I don't have an android. so Is there any chat messenger which can work in both her android in china and I can use in ubuntu? I am seeing pidgin for android.. but it's not free.

Comment: for wechat you can use the webinterface on PC: http://web.wechat.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype has a chat/instant message  feature. The Skype app is available for Android in Google Play Store (Android apps), and it also can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: thanx.. But I have managed to install kik using emaluator..

Comment: also facebook chat/hangout (web or empathy)

Comment: The icon to start Facebook Chat (web) is located in the lower right corner of your Facebook webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to share the same client, just the same protocol. You can use the XMPP protocol (AKA Jabber). There are many free providers, you can see some [here](http://xmpp.net/). Google used to use this protocol back when the messaging application was called Talk, but now it doesn't; so mind that. (You can revert to old protocol in Google AFAIK, but you should confirm that.)